Using Laravel query builder with Between and GETDATE
I'm trying to understand how I can create a query with query builder and have a where value something like
where item=1
and GETDATE() BETWEEN date1 AND date2
Thanks.

I've found this seems to work.
->whereRaw('? Between b.startDate AND b.endDate', array(now()))
